# How do I specify which Meteor Subscription should be used to render in React?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I have multiple Subscriptions and Publications for different views on the same collection. One of these views is used for returning a Text Search on the Mongo Collection, whilst other views return the entire collection.

My problem is when I try to view the results on client, I'm not sure how to specify to use the  search result subscription. Currently my client view is displaying the entire collection instead of the restricted search results. How do I specify which subscription should be used? Or am I misunderstanding the pub/sub model? Possibly I should only be using a single subscription? Any input appreciated!

```
// Server side publication
Meteor.publish("search", function(searchValue){
  if (!searchValue) {
    console.log("there is no search value");
    return remoteData.find({});
  }

  console.log("there is a search value and it is " + searchValue);
  return remoteData.find({$text:{$search: searchValue}});
});

Meteor.publish("allData", function (){
  return remoteData.find();
});

// Client Side subscription
var searchSubscription =  Meteor.subscribe("search", searchQuery);
var allDataSubscription =  Meteor.subscribe("allData");

// inside React Component 
// this returns everything, so I think it's using the allDataSubscription
filteredData() {
  return (
    remoteData.find({}).fetch();
  )
}
```

Comment: If all data is subscribed, all data will be available in minimongo. So, the search can be performed locally.

Comment: The problem is that $text is not currently supported by minimongo, as far as I can see the only way to get around this to do the $text search on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't really need to have two separate subscriptions. Just merge things into one subscription, so there is never any doubt. For example:

```
// Server
Meteor.publish('myData', function (searchValue) {
  const selector = {};
  if (searchValue) {
    selector.$text = {
      $search: searchValue,
    };
  }
  return remoteData.find(selector);
});

// Client
const myDataHandle =  Meteor.subscribe('myData', searchQuery);
...
remoteData.find({}).fetch();
```

Comment: This is pretty clever.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to specify data from different subscriptions to the same collection.** This is because Meteor combines the data from all subscriptions of a back-end collection to the same Minimongo collection in the front-end, and there is no distinction between data from different subscriptions.

Unfortunately for your case, this means there is no reliable way to reactively use the `$text` operator that Minimongo does not currently support. I'd recommend either replacing it with `$regex` operator that does work in the front-end, or writing a Meteor method that returns the ids for all matched documents, and using this list in the front-end like:

```js
remoteData.find({ _id: { $in: matchingIds } }).fetch();
```

You have to re-call this method when your search parameters change, since it's not reactive.

Comment: I hadn't considered using $regex, will look into this. Thanks!